# Foursquare API Categories

Tags: api, http, foursquare

I must be misunderstanding categories on the foursquare API and it is driving me crazy.

When I send this:

```
 https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=44.874491,-93.328212&client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX&v=20130327
```

I get all the venues as I would expect. However, if I do the categoryId for coffee shops as so:

```
 https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=44.874491,-93.328212&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d1e0931735&client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX&v=20130327
```

I lose the closest coffee shops that originally showed up. In particular, the one I'm sitting in with address of `7101 France Ave S`. This behavior has been consistently odd.

And then a second question: since `Coffee Shop` is a category below `Food`, should I not get them when I limit to `Food` category? If I do that:

```
 https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=44.874491,-93.328212&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259&client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX&v=20130327
```

I do not get a single coffee shop. This is driving me crazy and I know I must be missing something simple.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified in the Foursquare docs on [venues/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search), you should specify a `radius` parameter when using `categoryId`. Doing so with your search seems to return better results.

"Food" is a broad category and perhaps the results you are seeing are "better" matches for various reasons (popularity, proximity, etc.) Again, you should be specifying a `radius` when using `categoryId`. You ought to also look over the different `intent`s available for venues/search to find out which one is best for your app! It may help if you start using this param as well.

Comment: The radius fixed it. I didn't think to try that because the documentation is a little unclear, in my opinion. You guys should change the wording of the documentation to say `you should also specify a radius` rather than the current `you may also specify a radius`.